# Is memory shared between sub-processes in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I have following script

```
import multiprocessing as mp, logging

logger = logging.getLogger()


def setup_logger(name_logfile, path_logfile):
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:   %(message)s', datefmt='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(path_logfile, mode='w')
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)


def MyFunc(A):
    print(A)
    setup_logger('Logfile%s' % A, 'd:/Logfile%s.log' % A)
    logger.info('text to be written to logfile in %s' % A)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    with pool:
        pool.map(MyFunc, [1, 2])
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
    logger.warning("in main")
    print("done")
```

When i run it, i get 2 log files.

The output in **LogFile1.log**

```
2020/12/11 01:05:09:   text to be written to logfile in 1
2020/12/11 01:05:09:   text to be written to logfile in 2  <--
```

The output in **LogFile2.log**

```
2020/12/11 01:05:09:   text to be written to logfile in 2  <--
```

I thought the sub-processes have their own separate memory and dont share the `logger` object, but to my surprise the log line with 2 is written in both the files. And the `warning` log is never written.

Can someone please explain?

I ran this on windows machine with 4 CPUs and python 3.8

Comment: How is logger initialized? On Windows, the main script will be run from the start in each subprocess, but `if __name__ == '__main__'` blocks will not run.

Comment: `logger` is initialized globally but handlers are attached only in sub processes so I guess there are 3 logger objects, 1 in main process and 2 in sub processes

Comment: I ran your script for 1000 times and couldn't reproduce the results on either Mac or Linux (only systems I have access to) so this problem is most likely OS dependent.